# Are type definition statements equal?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, dllexport

I need to export template specialization.

**Are the following definitions equal?**

```
typedef std::vector<int> MY_API MyIntArray; // (1)

template class MY_API std::vector<int>; // (2)
typedef std::vector<int> MyIntArray;
```

Common `MY_API` macro definition looks like `#define MY_API __declspec(dllexport)`.

And another question is -- **does template specialization occur at `typedef std::vector<int> MyIntArray;`?**

---

*I've alreade seen a bunch of a question about using `STL` classes across modules/dll boundaries and potential issues.*

Comment: There are a lot of similar question, however I didn't find answer for questions above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No -- the `typedef` is a slightly (but only slightly) smarter version of a `#define`, that equates the specified name with the specified type. It adds an entry in the compiler's symbol table saying this name stands for that type.

A `typedef` does nothing more than that though. It specifically does *not* instantiate the specified type, so it is not equivalent to an explicit instantiation of the template in question. (As to why it explicitly doesn't instantiate the type: for one, because you can create a `typedef` of an incomplete type, which can't be instantiated until the type is completed).